# Chart.js: Fixed horizontal location of vertical axis

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

[image]

How can I guarantee a fixed horizontal location for the vertical axis in terms of pixel from the edge of the screen? The photo shows how the axis location varies depending on number of digits in the scale labels. (I need the X in the photo to be constant so the plot will line up with other elements on the page.)

I've tried adjusting:

- Options > layout > padding > left; and that shifts everything to the right but the location of the vertical axis still depends on the number of digits in the y-axis scale labels.
- Options > scales > yAxes > ticks > padding; that changes the space between the label and the axis but it doesn't guarantee a location for the vertical axis.

(I'm using options > responsive = false.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there's a better way, but this worked for me.

In the chart options I set: `options > layout > padding > left` to a default pixel amount that works for my situation when the scale label has only two digit number labels.

Then I set an ID for the yAxes so that I can access it later: `options > scales > yAxes > id`.

Then in my JavaScript, after the code that defines the chart, I added the following code which adjusts the left padding if the scale label has three digits (in my case I set it to 1):

```
var axis = myLineChart.scales.<id of my y axis>;
var max_tick_label = axis.ticks[0];
if (max_tick_label >= 100) {
    myLineChart.options.layout.padding['left'] = 1;
    myLineChart.update();
}
```